# Search in all folders of a subfolder for the presence of a specified file

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, path

I have a Main directory which has a bunch of sub directories , Each of these sub directories are expected to have an app.config file and I want to validate it . This app.config file can be any where of a given sub directory.
As of my implementation below I can check if this config file is immediately inside the given subdirectory (for example if the sub directory is "folder" I will check if the app.confg is available in the path folder\app.config ) but it fails to check if the app.config is in any where of the given sub directory.

IN the sense the app.config file can be inside of a sub direcotry of a given inital sub directory. bascically anywhere inside the given sub directory

Is there  any way I can implement this behavior ?

```
private void ValidateFiles(string path)
        {



            string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            foreach (var subDir in filesindirectory)
            {
                string pathToConfigFile = Path.Combine(subDir, "app.config");
                if (File.Exists(pathToConfigFile))
                {

                }

                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use Recursion to search all subdirectories

Comment: i think what you are looking for is a way to iterate through a directory tree. See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Directory.GetFiles` method to find your file inside a folder and in the `SearchOption` parameter pass the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to search in all subdirectories.
Here is the code sample for reference:

```
    private void ValidateFiles(string path)
    {
        var filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(path, "app.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var file in filesindirectory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
```

In the filesindirectory variable you will now have all the file names(which is app.config in our case) along with the path.
 
For more reference : [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: from this answer I can get all the paths of the existing folders which have the file , is there any way I can implement it such that I can implement so that names of all directories which do not have a config file can be printed

Comment: private static void Process(string path)
        {
            var filesindirectory = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => Path.GetExtension(x) != ".config"));
            var directoryNames = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (var file in filesindirectory)
            {
                directoryNames.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
            }
            foreach (var dir in directoryNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Recursion if your path contains subdirectories inside subdirectories.

```
private void ValidateFiles(string path)
        {
            DirSearch(path);
        } 


private void DirSearch(string sDir)
        {
            List<String> files = new List<String>();
            try
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
                {
                string pathToConfigFile = Path.Combine(sDir, "app.config");
                if (File.Exists(pathToConfigFile))
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }

                }
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {
                    files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var LstfileDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(path, "app.config",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .ToList();

LstfileDirectory.ForEach(Item => Console.WriteLine(Item));
```